# "Sorted(by: )" not returning an Array / how to sort an Array of PFObjects in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, pfobject

so I can't seem to sort using swifts built in sort function.

I have an Array of PFObjects, if you don't know what those are for the scope of this question it's probably better to imagine it as an array of hashTables.

I'm trying to sort the array using this

```
self.courseArray = self.courseArray.sorted(by: sortClasses)
```

and sortClasses looks like:

```
    func sortClasses(_ x: Any, _ y:Any) ->Bool{
    return ((x as! PFObject).object(forKey: "priority") as! Int) < ((y as! PFObject).object(forKey:"priority") as! Int)
}
```

Where the key priority will give an Int.

However, when I do this I get this error

```
Cannot assign value of type '[NSFastEnumerationIterator.Element]' to type 'NSMutableArray'
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use native Swift `Array` rather than `NSMutableArray`.

Declare `courseArray` as

```
[PFObject]()
```

and use key subscription

```
func sortClasses(_ x: Any, _ y:Any) -> Bool {
    return (x as! PFObject)["priority"] as! Int < (y as! PFObject)["priority"] as! Int
}
```

You might change other API related to `NSMutableArray` to the native counterparts.

Comment: The problem is courseArray needs to be a NSMutableArray for other spots in the code, do you know what the root of this problem is, from there I can probably figure out what I need to do.

Comment: There is no need at all to use `NSMutableArray` in Swift. Consider to update the *other spots* to conform to Swift's strong type system. It's worth it, believe me.